# SQL Server How to break apart each hour from a time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I am trying to calculate the amount of minutes per hour in a date range.

I would like it to return the amount of minuets that are in each hour. If the start time is `12:38PM` and the end time is `1:18PM` it would input `22` in the `12PM` column, and `18` in the `1PM` column. I am hoping to find a way to have it create the `24 hour` columns needed.

And then create another 24 columns and take the `Units_Sold/Minutes` and multiply them by the `minutes` in each hour to get the average total units sold per hour.

This is what I made it look line in Excel

[image: screenshot]

```
SELECT account_number,
       asset_number,
       units_sold,
       minutes,
       open_date,
       start_time,
       end_time
FROM sales
```

Comment: Can your times cross midnight? Cover whole days? Any particular flavor of SQL?

Comment: And welcome to SO, btw. Traditionally it is appropriate t show some attempt you've made as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This feel like an odd thing to do, but it certainly possible. I'll give you a starting point in TSQL, but it should translate.  It is pretty much brute force so I'd look for a clever/efficient alternative if doing this on an significant scale.

Also, I assumed we're not crossing days, but that could be handles pretty easily, probably using something like "Julian hours" which I don't think are real but would act like a [Julian day](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).

```
--set up a test table a couple test cases
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(start_time DATETIME2,end_time DATETIME2)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('2014-11-19 21:08:00.190', '2014-11-19 22:08:00.190')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('2014-11-19 20:08:00.190', '2014-11-19 22:08:00.190')

--use a common table expression to get the time parts (could be just a subquery)
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
      ,DATEPART(HH,start_time) start_hour
      ,DATEPART(MINUTE,start_time) start_min
      ,DATEPART(HH,end_time) end_hour
      ,DATEPART(MINUTE,end_time) end_min
  FROM @tbl
)
SELECT *
      ,CASE 
         WHEN end_hour < 0 THEN 0 --not real case for hour 0
         WHEN start_hour > 0 THEN 0
         WHEN end_hour = 0  AND start_hour = 0 THEN end_min - start_min
         WHEN start_hour = 0 AND end_hour > 0 THEN 60 - start_min
         WHEN start_hour < 0 AND end_hour = 0 THEN end_min --not real case for hour 0
         ELSE 60
        END [00]
       --...
       ,CASE 
         WHEN end_hour < 21 THEN 0 --not real case for hour 0
         WHEN start_hour > 21 THEN 0
         WHEN end_hour = 21  AND start_hour = 21 THEN end_min - start_min
         WHEN start_hour = 21 AND end_hour > 21 THEN 60 - start_min
         WHEN start_hour < 21 AND end_hour = 21 THEN end_min --not real case for hour 0
         ELSE 60
       END [21]
       ,CASE 
         WHEN end_hour < 22 THEN 0 
         WHEN start_hour > 22 THEN 0
         WHEN end_hour = 22  AND start_hour = 22 THEN end_min - start_min
         WHEN start_hour = 22 AND end_hour > 22 THEN 60 - start_min
         WHEN start_hour < 22 AND end_hour = 22 THEN end_min 
         ELSE 60
       END [22]
       --etc.
  FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `spt_values` to get 24 hours, then join your table to get every hours minutes, at last pivot to 24 columns.

```
with hours as
(
select number as hour
    from master..spt_values
    where number between 0 and 23 AND TYPE='P'
),
your_table as
(
 select convert( datetime , '2014-11-19 00:00:00.000') as start_dt
       ,convert( datetime , '2014-11-19 23:59:00.000') as end_dt
 union
 select convert( datetime , '2014-11-19 20:00:00.000') as start_dt
       ,convert( datetime , '2014-11-20 19:59:00.000') as end_dt
),
minutes as
(
select 
    t.start_dt,t.end_dt,h.hour,
    case 
      when datepart(hour,t.start_dt)=datepart(hour,t.end_dt)
        then datepart(MINUTE,t.end_dt)-datepart(MINUTE,t.end_dt)
      when datepart(hour,t.start_dt) = h.hour
        then 60 - datepart(MINUTE,t.start_dt)
      when datepart(hour,t.end_dt) = h.hour
        then datepart(MINUTE,t.end_dt) 
        else 60 end as minutes
from your_table t
join hours h
  on (datediff(day,t.start_dt,t.end_dt)=0 and h.hour between datepart(hour,t.start_dt) and datepart(hour,t.end_dt) )
    or (datediff(day,t.start_dt,t.end_dt)=1 and (h.hour <= datepart(hour,t.start_dt) or h.hour >= datepart(hour,t.end_dt) ))
)
select 
    start_dt,
    end_dt,
    [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],
    [12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23]
from minutes
pivot (max(minutes) for hour 
       in ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],
           [12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23]
          )) as p
```

Result:

```
START_DT            END_DT              0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
19 Nov 2014 00:00   19 Nov 2014 23:59   60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  59
19 Nov 2014 20:00   20 Nov 2014 19:59   60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  59  60  60  60  60
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23029)</kbd>